# Processing list of values in key argument for tikz plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I want to pass a list of two values as a key argument and be able to access and use them arbitrarily in a command defined by myself.

For example I want a command for plotting an arc of a circle with the following syntax

```
\MyCircle[angles={0,45},radius=1]{(2,2)}
```

in order to get the plot of an arc of circle centered in (2,2), starting angle 0°, final angle 45° and radius 1, that is

```
\draw (2,2) arc(0:45:1) ;
```

How can I split the angles list to access its single values and use them arbitrarily in a command? I have no difficulties in dealing with single key-values arguments. I'm currently using the keycommand package but also the pgfkey package would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to set existing TikZ keys with the parser then you can use `style args`. If you need a custom code to be executed then you can also use `code args` and proceed from there.

For the specific example, a possible way to do it:

```
\tikzset{angles/.style args={#1,#2}{start angle=#1, end angle=#2}}
\def\MyCircle[#1]#2{\draw #2 arc [#1];}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\MyCircle[angles={0,45},radius=1]{(2,2)}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But how to use the "start angle" as a variable in different places of a pictures?

Comment: @lecio You can use `code args` and then store it in a variable like `\def\myvar{#1}` and use it elsewhere